# iotop crashes on jetson nano

Tags: apt, nvidia, iotop

I am trying to install **iotop** on jetson nano, but I get a crash. How can I fix it? Are there some alternatives to **iotop**?

```
stiv@nano:~$ sudo apt install iotop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-clone archdetect-deb bogl-bterm busybox-static cryptsetup-bin dpkg-repack gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0
  grub-common kde-window-manager kinit kio kpackagetool5 kwayland-data kwin-common kwin-data kwin-x11 libc-ares2
  libdebian-installer4 libhttp-parser2.7.1 libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private5v5 libkf5activities5
  libkf5attica5 libkf5completion-data libkf5completion5 libkf5declarative-data libkf5declarative5 libkf5doctools5
  libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5idletime5 libkf5jobwidgets-data
  libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kiowidgets5
  libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5package-data libkf5package5 libkf5plasma5
  libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5
  libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5waylandserver5 libkf5xmlgui-bin
  libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui5 libkscreenlocker5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1 libkwineffects11 libkwinglutils11
  libkwinxrenderutils11 libqgsttools-p1 libqt5designer5 libqt5help5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins
  libqt5multimediaquick-p5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5
  libxcb-composite0 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-damage0 nodejs-doc os-prober python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 python3-icu
  python3-pam python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-sip
  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtquick2 rdate tasksel tasksel-data
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  iotop
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 282 not upgraded.
Need to get 21,4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 88,1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main arm64 iotop arm64 0.6-2 [21,4 kB]
Fetched 21,4 kB in 0s (54,8 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package iotop.
(Reading database ... 163968 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/iotop_0.6-2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking iotop (0.6-2) ...
Setting up iotop (0.6-2) ...
XXX too high nonterminal number!
XXX too high nonterminal number!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package iotop (--configure):
 installed iotop package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 139
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iotop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
stiv@nano:~$ iotop
XXX too high nonterminal number!
XXX too high nonterminal number!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: That's possibly generated by the **Curses** library.Can you please post a core dump of that? Firstly raise the **core dump** size from zero to **unlimited** temporarily by running ```ulimit -c unlimited```.

Comment: I get: sudo: ulimit: command not found

Comment: **ulimit** is not necessarily required.The core dump should be in ```/var/lib/systemd/coredump``` right after the crash.

Comment: Just go there and run ```unlz4 coredumpfilename /tmp/iotop.dump```(you have to install ```liblz4-tool``` first) .And then run ```gdb python3``` and inside that shell run ```core /tmp/iotop.dump```.It should show you what was the exact error that leads to segmentation fault.